# Application warming up or initialisation after making a web.config change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, initialization, iis-7.5

To warm up an application, I have applied Application Initialisation settings by making some config changes on applicationhost.config file on iis 7.5. these works fine when I recycle an application pool or restart IIS. i have picked up these settings from here (http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/terri/implementing-application-initialization-on-iis-7-5/)

these setting doesn't work when i make any web.config changes. is there a way to recycle an application pool automatically when i make a change in web.config file?

Comment: Application Pool can have multiple applications. Recycling the APPpool will recycle all teh apps in it. Are you sure you want to do that?? When you make changes to the web.config the server is smart enough to pick up the new changes.

Comment: We only keep one app pool per application. I know that web.config changes will be picked up by IIS but i want to reduce that delay on loading app for the first time after you make any change in web.config or release a new dll. (FYI I need this solution for Restful services because when we do any config change then first call to that service takes long).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to read up on this [post](http://www.treeloop.com/blog/iis-application-domain-and-pool-recycling) - nicely explains difference between Application domain recycle vs. application pool recycle. Imagine scenario where there are two apps sharing same app pool, recycling whole pool because of one app config change is not really desired.To answer your question, I am not aware there is a setting and I believe app pool recycle should be done manually or via [pool recycle settings](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling#005).